# How to pass the value of a c ++ variable to a bash system command of hadoop HDFS?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a variable received from the input file of my hadoop streaming.
The input file contains the name of a video for example :

### Input_file.txt:

### Video0001.mp4

I stored the value of the input in the variable ***key***

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[]){
    string key;
    string value ="1";
    while(cin>>key) {
        system("/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/Video0001.mp4 /home/master/Desktop/Extract_signature/BDs/");
        system("mkdir /home/master/Desktop/Extract_signature/SIGN");
        // ....
        // ....
    }
}
```

My goal is to replace the video name with the value of the **Key** variable and run the system command

So replace

```
system("/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/Video0001.mp4
```

by

```
system("/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/<Value of key>
```

Comment: Not much to do with the [tag:hdfs] or [tag:hadoop-streaming] tags, more a question about how to use `std::string` in conjunction with `system()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the whole parameter for `system()` with a `std::string` (or [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)) and pass it to `system()` using the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function of the result:

```
std::string hadoopCmd = "/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/";
hadoopCmd += key;
system(hadoopCmd.c_str());
```

---

This version is more flexible regarding the formatting of other types than `std::string` as `key`:

```
std::ostringstream hadoopCmd;
hadoopCmd << "/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/"
          << key;
system(hadoopCmd.str().c_str());
```

Comment: My command is : `system("/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/BDs/Video0001.mp4 /home/master/Desktop/Extract_signature/BDs/");` and key is the name of video :video0001.mp4

Comment: @MEHDISAOUDI And what? The code I proposed will work properly.